# $(this) alternative of angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to do something similar in AngularJS with this jquery code

```
x = $(this).next().next().val();
alert(x);
```

The HTML code is:

```
<span ng-click="ajax_update_button()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="cursor: pointer; color: red;"></span>
<span ng-click="ajax_delete([[ x.id ]])" style="cursor: pointer; color: red;">X</span> ----- 
<span>[[ x.name ]]</span>
```

angular javacript is:

```
var StudentListSystem = angular.module('StudentListSystem', ['ngRoute']);

StudentListSystem.controller('SectionFormController', function($scope, $http){          
    $scope.ajax_delete = function(id){
        // alert(id);
        $http.delete('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/section/'+id)
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.Notifications = true;
            $scope.Deleted = response.data;
            // alert(JSON.stringify(response));
            $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/section/')
            .then(function(response){
                $scope.Sections = response.data;
            });
        }, function(response){
            $scope.Notifications = true;
            $scope.Errors = response.data;
        });
    }
    $scope.ajax_update_button = function(event){
        x = $(this).next().next().text();
        $(this).next().next().html("<input type='text' value='"+x+"'>");
    }
});
```

Main question is that I am looking for an alternative of $(this) from jquery to angularjs

Comment: What you want to do with `this`? Just to access the value of span?

Comment: Many things, like changing the text of the next two spans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating HTML, you should use [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive to render the desired HTML using the flag value i.e. `edit` in my example.

> The `ngIf` directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an `{expression}`. If the expression assigned to `ngIf` evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

You can directly pass `x` to the function as

```
 <span ng-click="ajax_update_button(selectedCustomer)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" style="cursor: pointer; color: red;">Update</span>
 <span>
 <span ng-if="!selectedCustomer.edit">{{selectedCustomer.name}}</span>
 <span ng-if="selectedCustomer.edit"><input type='text' ng-model="selectedCustomer.name"></span>
 </span>
```

Then you can access its properties and manipulate the object as per your requirement

```
$scope.selectedCustomer = {
 name: "Male",
 edit:false
};

$scope.ajax_update_button = function(selectedCustomer){
     selectedCustomer.edit = !selectedCustomer.edit;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/z1pLcqL4/)

Comment: I edited the contents of ajax_update_button, but my real intention is turning the text of the last span tag into an input text with the text of the last span as its value

Comment: Can I ask for more knowledge? After making it to an input text I plan to have a focus out functionality and then trigerring it to an api through $http.update

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada you can use `ngblur` directive